# Shouldn't Gallian state $\Leftarrow$ for $a\ne0?$

Tags: ring-theory

Gallian text says in an integral domain $D,$ $a$ is a prime element $\iff(a)$ is a prime ideal of $D.$

Showing $\Rightarrow$ is easy. But I can see that $(0)$ is a prime ideal of $D$ (since $D/(0)$ is an integral domain) even though $0$ is not a prime element.

Shouldn't Gallian state $\Leftarrow$ for $a\ne0?$

Comment: If $(p)$ is a prime ideal, then $D/(p)$ should be a field. It is trivial that $D=D/(0)$. However, it is not obvious from what you've stated that $D$ is a field.

Comment: Also, if $(0)$ is a prime ideal, then $(0,a)=D$. Where $a$ is any element $\in D$. This is obviously not true. Hence $(0)$ is not a prime ideal

Comment: I don't think your first claim is true, @AyushKhaitan : in a commutative unitary ring $\,R\,$ , an ideal $\,I\le R\,$ is prime iff $\,R/I\,$ is *an integral domain*, not necessarily a field.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan: $(0)$ is a proper ideal of $D.$ $xy\in(0)\implies xy=0\implies x=0~or~y=0\implies x\in(0)~or~y\in(0)\implies(0)$ is a prime ideal of $D.$

Comment: And yes: $\{0\}\,$ is too a prime ideal in any integral domain. I think Sriti's right: Gallian apparently forgot the requirement $\,a\neq 0\,$...or perhaps he considers zero as a prime element *in an integral domain*, which wouldn't be that odd after all...

Comment: @DonAntonio: Gallian didn't assume zero to be prime. His definition for prime element begins as: A non-zero non-unit element is said to be ...

Comment: I just read that now, Sriti: all that happens in the same page (259, chapter 20) and within very few lines, so it must be seen as a little ommision, imho.

Comment: @SritiMallick- true, sorry I was using "prime ideal" interchangeably with "maximal ideal". Both of my claims are true for maximal ideals.